# My phone is stuck in a loop

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, boot, unbricking

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy Young GT S6312.
It does not boot up at all. I have made a video of the loop as shown here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t38NYXvawmxSiIK9gqRTLINoIvG158Vi6w/view?usp=drivesdk

What is the problem?

I flashed the stock rom many times but it doesn't fix. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My Android 4.4.2 tablet puts the image at 0:48 on-screen during a factory reset, if it helps. Did you try to factory reset your phone? It may have improperly reset and been put into a bootloop.

Comment: My phone switched off suddenly and I tried to boot into recovery but just at the moment it started the loop. I didn't try to factory reset. Thanks for a reply Zachary.

Comment: Can you access the bootloader? If so, you (should) be able to fix the bootloop by reflashing the stock ROM.

Comment: I flashed the stock rom many times but it doesn't fix.